# Counting occurrences of matched words

Tags: unix, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [need code in awk unix or use substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054466/need-code-in-awk-unix-or-use-substr)

I want to print words between `ctr{words}` and count the frequencies of the words.

I tried:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*ctr{\(.[^}]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

The code works and print out the words perfectly but I need to count the frequencies of the words.

The output of the above code:

```
Mo7afazat
JaishanaIN
ZainElKul
ZainUnlimited
AlBarakehNew
ZainElKulSN
```

But I need:

```
1 Mo7afazat
1 JaishanaIN
2 ZainElKul
1 ZainUnlimited
1 AlBarakehNew
1 ZainElKulSN
```

The file is:

```
962796057604|mar0101|0|00000107A20E00000A6C331650B920340C00|0|0|400019FD7DBFBF7F|1001|962796057604|0 |01001|||-1|795971936|  00962795971936|16||-1|  00962795971936|-1|0|2|0|416019000659493|0||||||0|0|2012.12.01 00:07:09|12|30|0|516|16|1|2012.12.01 00:06:39|1|0||202|20001||0B12F1001104697209100300000000000000|1|1|11000|0|0||0881006972091003F000||0 714F610045584E6|000000000000|3|1|0000000000000000|0|140|0|0|0|0|0|0|||0|2|||||||||||||||||||||0|||0| |0|1|143|acf{0}cif{0}fcf{0}con{0}cuf{0}ctr{**Mo7afazat**}cgpa{962796057604}vlr{0096279001300}cff{0}roaf{0}mpty{0}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{CallTicketCPOCS} ||
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-962796298894|mar0101|0|000001028225AE4AD868A8B750B900980C00|1|0|4000018001000002||962796298894|||||-1|||||-1||-1|0||||0||||||-1|-1|||-1|0|-1|-1|-1|2012.12.01 00:08:35|1|0||-1|0|||||||||||||0|0|||3797|0|12|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||1|6|244|tid{111210532409329884}pfid{20}gob{1}rid{globitel} afid{}uid1{962796298894}aid1{1}ar1{0}uid2{globitel}aid2{-1}pid{1234}pur{!GDRC COMMIT AMOUNT 0}ratinf{}rec{0}rots{0}tda{}mid{}exd{0}reqa{0}ctr{**JaishanaIN**}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{PayCallTicket}||
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|100-50-0-962796605155|mar0101|0|00000102A20400000A6A439D50B920520C00|0|0|400019FD7DBFBF7F|1001|962796605155|1 6||||-1|b116c||16||-1||-1|0|0|0|416017002233360|0||||||0|0|1970.01.01 02:00:00|0|0|0|220|0|1|1970.01.01 02:00:00|1|0||194|0||000000000000000000000000000000000000|0|0||0|0||00000000000000000000||0000000000 000000|000000000000|0|0|0000000000000000|0|370|0|0|0|0|0|0|||0|0|||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||0|1|70|a cf{3}ussd{1}ctr{**ZainElKul**}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{CallTicketCPOCS}||
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|100-10-0
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-962797611253|mar0101|0|0000010282B54BD015FF4C4B50B8F96E0C00|1|0|4000018001000002||962797611253|||||-1|||||-1||-1|0||||0||||||-1|-1|||-1|0|-1|-1|-1|2012.12.01 00:08:35|1|0||-1|0|||||||||||||0|0|||885|0|12|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||1|6|243|tid{111220371293561120}pfid{20}gob{1}rid{globitel} afid{}uid1{962797611253}aid1{1}ar1{0}uid2{globitel}aid2{-1}pid{1234}pur{!GDRC COMMIT AMOUNT 0}ratinf{}rec{0}rots{0}tda{}mid{}exd{0}reqa{0}ctr{**ZainElKul**}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{PayCallTicket}||

-962795292027|mar0101|0|00000101A20200000A6A96B750B920300C00|0|0|400019FD7DBFBF7F|1001|962795292027|0 |01004|||-1|797196452|  00962797196452|16||-1|  00962797196452|-1|0|2|0|416018002276781|0||||||0|0|2012.12.01 00:07:09|12|12|23|516|16|1|2012.12.01 00:06:34|1|0||202|1||0B12F1001104697209100300000000000000|1|1|11000|0|0||0881006972091003F000||0714F 6100455AD67|000000000000|3|1|0000000000000000|0|30|0|0|0|0|0|0|||0|0|||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||0|1| 171|acf{0}cif{0}fcf{0}con{0}cuf{0}ctr{ZainUnlimited}cgpa{962795292027}vlr{0096279001300}cff{0}roaf{0}mpty{0}cacc{1;0;30}cquo{1;230;}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{000 1}ftktp{CallTicketCPOCS}||
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-962796012818|mar0101|0|0000010882218115085D5F9150B920520C00|0|0|4000018001000002||962796012818|||||-1|||||-1||-1|0||||0||||||-1|-1|||-1|0|-1|-1|-1|2012.12.01 00:08:35|1|0||-1|1|||||||||||||0|0|||70|0|0|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||1|6|258|tid{111221366974701289}pfid{17}gob{1}rid{globitel} afid{}uid1{962796012818}aid1{1}ar1{-2147483648}uid2{}aid2{-1}pid{DEFAULT_DECISION}pur{!GDRC Balance Check}ratinf{}rec{0}rots{0}tda{}mid{}exd{0}reqa{0}ctr{**AlBarakehNew**}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{PayCallTicket}||
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-962797251349|mar0101|0|0000010282A451483EDFCFD350B920400C00|1|0|4000018001000002||962797251349|||||-1|||||-1||-1|0||||0||||||-1|-1|||-1|0|-1|-1|-1|2012.12.01 00:08:35|1|0||-1|0|||||||||||||0|0|||440|0|12|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|-2147483648|||||||||||||||||||||||||0|||0||1|6|245|tid{111211342745325133}pfid{20}gob{1}rid{globitel} afid{}uid1{962797251349}aid1{1}ar1{0}uid2{globitel}aid2{-1}pid{1234}pur{!GDRC COMMIT AMOUNT 0}ratinf{}rec{0}rots{0}tda{}mid{}exd{0}reqa{0}ctr{**ZainElKulSN**}ftksn{JMT}ftksr{0001}ftktp{PayCallTicket}||
1|34|2012.12.01 00:08:35|12|4|921-*203-0000000000-
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `| sort | uniq -c` at the end of your one-liner.

It becomes :

```
sed -n 's/.*ctr{\(.[^}]*\).*/\1/p' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: ok i mean i need sum of the similar words and words which no similar put number 1 like this:

zainlkul 10 

mo7afzat 1
......etc

Comment: Your question is not clear. The answer I've given gives you the number of unique occurences for each similar word, that seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: my friend as example if we have in above file three words "zainlkul" and ten words "mo7afazat" in output i want to print: zainlkul 3 mo7afzat 10 ......etc

Comment: Alright - so this is exactly what my above answer (and the other answers) do.

Comment: -1 you need to sort before running `uniq -c`.

Comment: Very right @dogbane. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to use regex for this, look:

```
cat test.txt | tr "}" "\n" | grep "ctr" | cut -d "{" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
  1 AlBarakehNew
  1 JaishanaIN
  1 Mo7afazat
  2 ZainElKul
  1 ZainElKulSN
  1 ZainUnlimited
```

Comment: my friend i need sum of similar words and other words which no same cout it like this :
 1  AlBarakehNew
 10  Mo7afazat
  2 ZainElKul

Comment: I wouldn't consided not using regex as an advantage here given all the extra piping needed, slightly better: `tr "}" "\n" < file | fgrep ctr | cut -d'{' -f2 | uniq -c` this drops the useless use of `cat`use `fgrep` for fixed string searching and drops `sort` as alpahbetical sorting is not required here.

Comment: You need `sort` otherwise `uniq -c` won't work.

Comment: @dogbane that statement isn't 100% true `uniq -c` **works** independently of `sort` **however** if the duplicate words aren't consecutive the output won't be as expected, here the duplicate words are so you can save a process. A sorted file has the property of consecutive duplicates but the reverse isn't true and without `sort` here the order is preserved.

Comment: The OP has not stated that duplicated words are consecutive, so you shouldn't be making such an assumption. And if you do, you need to state your assumptions explicitly in your answer.

Comment: @dogbane it is not an assumation, the OP gives the input and the required output. The required output asked for by the OP preserves the order, using `sort` does not preserved the order. I agree it should be noted the `uniq -c` counts on consecutive duplicates which is mentioned in `man uniq` but the use of `sort` here is not needed and the output given doesn't match that which is required in the question.